# User listing in wp-admin user.php / user list page

Tags: list, wp-admin

I need to display some custom order in user list page, but I need to use two type of `meta_keys`, one is working how can I add another one?

This is I tried with one with `meta_key`, I need another one (meta_key) to use

```
$query->set('meta_key', 'my_user_dob');
$query->set('meta_compare', '<');
$query->set('meta_value', 'Value');
```

No errors found in this code, but I need to insert another `meta_key`

```
$query->set('meta_key', 'my_user_dob');
$query->set('meta_compare', '<');
$query->set('meta_value', 'Value');
```

Comment: My full Code : function wpd_filter_users( $query ) {
  
      $idnumber = trim(get_user_meta( $user_id, 'idnumber', true ));                           
        $screen = get_current_screen();
       if( current_user_can('cashier') && 'users' == $screen->base ){                   
        $query->set('meta_key', 'my_user_dob');
        $query->set('meta_compare', '<');
        $query->set('meta_value', $idnumber );                
        }
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_users', 'wpd_filter_users' );

Comment: You can edit and append full code snippet

Comment: Try asking on WordPress.stackexhange